# nme.display.TileSheet doesn't exist?

Tags: intellij-idea, haxe, nme

Working in Haxe & NME. When trying to import the package for TileSheet nme.display.TileSheet doesn't show up. Only browser.display.TileSheet and native.display.TileSheet. Am I missing something?..

Answer (score 0):

Define a Haxe conditional compilation macro:
display

In IntelliJ this is in module settings.

---

I saw the conditional compilation flag looking at the src code...

```
package nme.display;
#if display
```

https://github.com/haxenme/NME/blob/master/nme/display/Tilesheet.hx